# How can I make video black and white in the VSE

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, color

I have strips of video in the VSE but I want to remove the color from them. How can I do this and get a pleasing result, and can I re-use the effect on other strips?

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can use modifiers, but there is a Saturation value in every strip's properties.

[image: Strip properties desaturate]

But it doesn't allow you to use a nice balance of colour components, to do that you need to add a Hue modifier. I choose to use an Adjustment Effect Strip so that I can duplicate it and re-use it elsewhere in the VSE timeline. Set it to S for saturation then drag down all of the hue nodes. You can do a selective colour effect at this time by leaving one of the values at its original position

[image: modifier desaturate]

But this just looks like the original desaturation effect. So we need to add a Curve modifier above it, then modify the relative contribution of each colour channel. We simply alter the curves so that they represent greater contrast for each colour.

[image: balance desaturate]

Now don't be fooled by this last image, I am only using one Curve modifier, but I have displayed it so that you can see what I did to each channel.